# Scalar- Valued Function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, padding

I have a function that works however, it's returning variable lengths???

```
[dbo].[StringPadRight]
   (@String as Varchar(max),
    @Length as int,
    @Char as char(1))
RETURNS Varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @PaddedString as Varchar(max)

    -- Return same string if @Length is smaller or equal to the length of @String value
    --  If(Len(@String) >= @Length )
    --       RETURN @String

    -- Create PaddedString
    Set @PaddedString = @String + Replicate('*', @Length - Len(@String))

    -- Return the PaddedString
    RETURN @PaddedString
 END
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

White Bread (thick)*******************************  2.75    Bread
White Bread (thin)********************************  2.75    Bread
Brown Bread***************************************  2.75    Bread
Stone Ground WW Bread*****************************  2.75    Bread
Rye Bread*****************************************  3.50    Bread
9 Grain Bread*************************************  2.75    Bread
Raisin Bread**************************************  3.25    Bread
Baguettes*****************************************  2.25    Bread
Why not sure why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please post the results as actual results and not an image? Also, how did you call your function to get these results?

Comment: That's not a fixed width font. Are you sure the lengths aren't the same?

Comment: dbo.StringPadright(rtrim(p.Name_en),50,'.') is the calling function

Comment: If you look at your output in a fixed-width font like courier is it all the same width then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is working as expected.   All string results are the same length.   They just look like different lengths because you are looking at them in a variable-width font, where some characters are wider than others.

Pasting your results into a courier font reveals they are all the same width, as does actually counting the characters.

Comment: YES, OMG, this is what it was needed to use a fixed font :D  Many thanks everyone ..